# Python bin() and leading zeros

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation

As of Python 3 the leading zeros are excluded in a `bin()` conversion.

I am trying to manipulate a value and re-arrange the bits so I can decode an offset but after the conversion I am loosing the leading zeros from the value.

Which would be the best way to do that without losing the leading zeros?

Here is the code :

```py
bytefeed = 0x0229  # which becomes 0x2902

def decodebytes(bytefeed, negative = True):

    rearrangedbits = list()
    reversed_dat.extend([bytefeed[1], bytefeed[0]])
    reversed_datdec = int.from_bytes(reversed_dat, byteorder='big', signed=False)
    bitfield2 = list(bin(reversed_datdec)[2:])
    rearrangedbits += bitfield2[4:10]
    rearrangedbits += bitfield2[0:4]
    rearrangedbits += bitfield2[10:17]
    bitfieldec2 = int("".join(map(str, rearrangedbits)),2)
    decovaroffset = finaloffset - bitfieldec2

    print(bitfield2)
    return decovaroffset
```

the result of the bitfield2 is :

```py
['1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0']
```

Should be :

```py
['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0']
```

`zfill()` is not an option here as the padding will affect the offset if the variables does not have leading zero.

Comment: What do you mean by "the padding will affect the offset if the variables does not have leading zero"?

Comment: everytime bytefeed changes with a non leading 0 value wouldn't that shift the complete value? var is not a constant .. was defined as a constant only for posting the issue

Answer (score 0):

seems that `zfill()` fixes the issue for the list as i had previously misunderstood the usage..

so

```
bitfield2 = list(bin(reversed_datdec)[2:])
```

should be

```
bitfield2 = list(bin(reversed_datdec)[2:].zfill(16))
```